# AngularJS - object property binds fine to one element and doesnt want to bind to another

Tags: angularjs

not sure why but the property binds just fine to textarea and doesnt want to bind to a text box...

Here is HTML:

```
<form method="post" ng-submit="vm.executeAction('CompleteWorkOrder')">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="resolutionNote">@("Resolution Note".T())</label>
        <textarea name="resolution" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Provide resolution..." ng-bind="vm.woComplete.Resolution" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="completionDate">@("Completion Date".T())</label>
        <input type="text" name="completionDate" class="form-control" ng-bind="vm.woComplete.Resolution" required>
    </div>
    <label>@("MRT".T()) {{vm.data.MRT}}</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the result

[image]

**Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the **text content** of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the **text content** when the value of that expression changes.

In your screenshot you can see that the text you entered in the text area DOES appear between the `<input>` and `</input>` tags. But, while that's fine for a textarea, that's not how an input works. An input stores it's data in the `value` attribute. You would want to use `ng-model` to get what you want.